# Network diagram drawing software

Tags: diagram

I need a software to draw a logical overview of my network infrastructure. I have several core switches across multiple locations, which split to around 400 hosts. I want to document each switch port and where they connect to. I also want to tag wires with IDs, and once the ID is entered on the software, I can immediately know which wire it is and the 2 ports it connects to.

Free, open source, and Linux software are preferred over proprietary Windows ones.

Is there any software that matches my criteria?

Comment: [Diagrams: Electron-based and open source](https://www.diagrams.net). Perhaps it is sufficient, but it's not specifically aimed at the purpose you want it for.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia: Graphical Network Simulator-3 is a network software emulator first released in 2008. It allows the combination of virtual and real devices, used to simulate complex networks.

https://www.gns3.com/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A free, well established desktop software and multi-platform is [yEd - Graph editor](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed). Also available as web version.